# ws2811 LED lights powered by Raspberry pi 3B+ sometimes produced the wrong color

Tags: led, ws2812

I am using a 3B+ pi to power Alitov 5V ws2811 LEDs. A link to the exact lights can be found [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01AG923GI).

To power the lights, I am using a 5V 10A power supply. To control the lights, I have connected the data line to the GPIO10 on the pi.

My circuit is very simple. I have the GPIO10 pin in series with a 1k Ohm resistor which is connected to the data line of the LEDs. The ground of the pi is wired in parallel with the power supply ground and the LED ground. The power is wired directly (through a breadboard) to the LEDs' power. I know that a shifting the data line from 3.3V to 5V is recommended, but I will get into why I did not do that in the next part. I am using the neopixel python library to control the LEDs.

The problem that I am having is that occasionally when I update the color of the LEDs, the color is incorrect. For example, when I run the code below, all the LEDs turn red, but roughly 1/4 color updates turn the LEDs yellowish-green. As well, the first LED normally flashes or is some other color. I found that when I touch the resistor/data line, the first few LEDs turn white and sometimes all the LEDs (not including the now white LEDs) turn blue. This seems to indicate some sort of hardware issue.

```
import board
import neopixel
import time

pixel_pin = board.D10
num_pixels = 50
ORDER = neopixel.RGB
pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(
    pixel_pin, num_pixels, auto_write=False, pixel_order=ORDER
)
#pixels.fill((255,255,255))
pixels.fill((255, 255, 255))
pixels.show()
time.sleep(4)
while True:
    pixels.fill((255, 0, 0))
    #for i in range(5, 25):
    #    pixels[i] = [0, 255, 0]
    pixels.show()
    time.sleep(2)
```

If I shift the data line voltage, using this [tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/neopixels-on-raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-wiring), I lose all control of the LEDs. This is why I have the data line directly connected.

Earlier, on another post, I had asked for help on a similar issue, and after specifying the color order in the code, the LEDs seemed to work. Then, the LEDs stopped working. After messing with the LEDs even more, I was able to get them to work by touching my finger to the ground. One night, I was able to get the lights to work after I let go by touching the 3-6 pin area on the pi. However, once I powered the lights off, I was never able to reproduce this effect or the other effect. Now, I am very lost and am wondering if I damaged the lights or pi. I have three strips of the lights and all of them reproduce the same issue, so I find it unlikely that the lights are damaged. I should note that I do not have an oscilloscope, so I cannot measure the signal of the data line. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have the ground for the light power connected to ground on the pi as well?

Comment: Why did you "in series with a 1k Ohm resistor"? You can not run reliably with 3.3V logic, although I normally use a MOSFET level shifter. Your connections are unclear.

Comment: The three grounds are in parallel. I have the power source ground attached to the "-" line on the breadboard and the lights ground and pi ground are plugged into that line on the breadboard. For the resistor, I just directly connected the GPIO10 pin to the data pin of the lights. However, I also put a 1k ohm resistor between the GPIO10 pin and the data pin. I understand that the 3.3V logic is not ideal, but what is weird is that it did work, as long as I placed my finger in the right place.

Comment: I should also mention that GPIO10 is the only pin that works. When I used GPIO18, none of the LEDs turned on.

Comment: idek but it works now. Seems like it must be a software thing because I didn't change my circuit at all. Also, GPIO18 works now.